# AWS-SDK for NodeJS: how to get credentials being used in program

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am accessing AWS sdk and its services like this in my code:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
```

I want to see what are the credentials being picked up when I initialise the S3 object. I tried following ways and clearly I am unable to figure out from the documentation how to use the methods and classes properly.

```
var credo = aws.config.Credentials().get();
var credo = aws.config.Credentials;
var credo = aws.config.credentials;
var credo = aws.Credentials().get();
var credo = aws.Credentials();
var credo = aws.Credentials;
```

Can someone tell me the right way to get this data? I am not finding aws documentation easy to understand for this part.

Edit: I am able to update credentials in code using `aws.config.update({accessKeyId: 'xxx', secretAccessKey: 'yyy', sessionToken:'zzz'`

I want to see what these values are when I dont set them like this. Process environment variables are not set. I have credentials file set up correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the globally configured credentials from `aws.config.credentials`

Get the accessKeyId:

```
var accessKeyId = aws.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
```

Get the secretAccessKey:

```
var secretAccessKey = aws.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at Nodes environment variables.

You can access all enviroment variables through the `process.env`

Specifically, you want this:

```
console.log(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
console.log(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
```

Comment: process.env variables are not set. I have the credentials file set up correctly.  I want to see what is S3 using, coz I feel it should be picking up the credentials from the file listed under "default".

Comment: When I add the code mentioned here, I get error saying "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is not defined" and  "undefined" respectively.

Comment: Ah, I typically set via environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

For modern NodeJS the recommended approach is to use awaits:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function main() {
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials();
  // retrieves credentials according to configuration precedence
  // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html
  // updates credentials if expired
  await AWS.config.credentials.getPromise()
  // after we ensured that credentials are ready we use them
  const accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
  const secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
  const sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
}
```